# "You are not allowed to call this method" with wp_remote_post() function

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I am trying to receive data from the WHISE API http://api.whise.eu/WebsiteDesigner.html#section/Tabs/Variables-and-collections and post it into my Wordpress website via the wp_remote_post() function. I'm using the Bearer token for authentication.

```
$url = 'https://api.whise.eu/v1/estates/list';
$body = array(
    'Filter' => array( 'languageId' => 'nl-BE'),
);

$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
];
    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking'    => true,
    'headers' => $headers,
    'body'        => json_encode($body),
    'cookies'     => array()
    )
);
 
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
    echo 'Response:<pre>';
    print_r( $response );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

But unfortunately I'm receiving this error in the body.

```
 [body] => {"isValidRequest":false,"validationErrors":[{"message":"You are not allowed to call this method","code":"MethodCallNotAllowed"}]}
```

I’m having a hard time finding solution for this problem.